# Upgrading from 2.2.5 to 2.2.6 several problems encrypt key exceed 32 character and layout

Tags: magento2, layout, upgrade, setup-upgrade

I'm working on upgrading my store from 2.2.5 to 2.2.6
I'm following this with my cron jobs of

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html

first problem arises at php bin/magento setup:upgrade
It says encrypt key can not exceed 32 characters. 
when I count it is 32. By deleting a part of the key in app/etc/env.php
it seems to work but can i do this without consequence ?
QUESTION: can you just change or delete a big part of the key in app/etc/env.php without any consequence ??

It seems to work all but my layout is screwed. I did remove image cahce and run image resize command.
Ves image slider on my cms home page is not showing the whole image anymore and all products in my widgets on my cms home page are not following the grid template anymore ?? It seems like list template ?

The navigation menu now has some small squares in there

In a catagory in the storefront the products are showing with the footer color as background

Cookie notice has changed color and location form bottom to top.

And last below the copyright and all there is some customer account create stuff.

Did i do something wrong ?
can any one help me fix any of my issues ??